# Do I need to use a heat sink?

Tags: temperature, pi-3

I ordered a Pi 3 and accessory kit [here from Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00L87YMGM), it comes with 2 heat sinks. I won't be overclocking the Pi, would I still need to worry about heat issues? Eventually, this will be in an enclosed area outside of the casing with plenty of air circulation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the cooling requirements for Raspberry Pi 3?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43357/what-are-the-cooling-requirements-for-raspberry-pi-3)

Comment: I asked a similar question here:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/55053/how-much-difference-do-the-stick-on-heat-sinks-make  - and the enclosure is what makes the most difference.  But in the end, neither changed it more than a couple of degrees.  I see an answer that talks about throttling but have never noticed that, even on hot days.  Still, I did order a new enclosure with a small fan, and do use the heat sinks.

Comment: You can also add a fan :P As in my answer http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/62171/56121

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No a heatsink is not required, The Pi3 has been reported to generate more heat than previous models, but the heatsink is not required. You can install it for some extra thermal protection, but the Pi will throttle the clock speed to maintain a safe temperature. Heatsinks are included in many of these kits to increase the perceived value.

Comment: I don't know how intrusive the throttling will be, or what load the OP has in mind, but I'd argue that a heatsink might be necessary to reach the necessary performance point in some scenarios - maybe mostly dictated by the 'enclosed area' or by the application...

Comment: I had this question about the RPi 3B+, so I did a before/after measurement. Without heat sinks, the CPU ran between 59C and 61C. With heat sinks, it runs between 52C and 54C.

Answer (score 11):

As the answers state, no heatsinks are required.

However, following on from [Snowman's comment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43752/do-i-need-to-use-a-heat-sink#comment-63950) to [Maxthon Chan's answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43752/do-i-need-to-use-a-heat-sink#answer-43757), and taking some examples from the Raspberry Pi site<sup>1</sup>, should you want to check/measure the temperature that your Pi is running at, you can use the command:

```
/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp
```

Should you find yourself using this command frequently, you may wish for a shortcut. To do this, you could use an *alias*, such as `temp`. To set this up, run the following commands:

```
cd ~
nano .bash_aliases
```

and add the following line

```
alias temp='/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp'
```

#### In case of error

Note that, should you be running an older version of Raspbian, and encounter the error:

> /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd: error while loading shared libraries: libvcos.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

then you should run

```
 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/vc/lib /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp
```

and the alias would become

```
alias temp="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/vc/lib && /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp"
```

#### Alternative

Run the following command, which gives the answer in millidegrees Centigrade, and divide by 1000 to get °C:

```
cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
```

#### Bash script for CPU and GPU temperatures

```
#!/bin/bash
cpuTemp0=$(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp)
cpuTemp1=$(($cpuTemp0/1000))
cpuTemp2=$(($cpuTemp0/100))
cpuTempM=$(($cpuTemp2 % $cpuTemp1))

gpuTemp0=$(/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp)
gpuTemp0=${gpuTemp0//\'/º}
gpuTemp0=${gpuTemp0//temp=/}

echo CPU Temp: $cpuTemp1"."$cpuTempM"ºC"
echo GPU Temp: $gpuTemp0
```

---

<sup>1</sup> All examples taken from [Show RPI's Temperature with a command](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=34994)

Comment: For the temp alias to work, you need to run
source .bash_aliases This will re-load the .bash_aliases file, which is what rebooting or re-logging in does, just without the wait. From:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=144613

Comment: It would probably be better to add a permanent entry to `ld.so.cache` (eg. via `sudo bash echo /opt/vc/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opt-vc.conf && sudo ldconfig`) than applying `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  I think this already exists by default in current Raspbian.

Answer (score 3):

No heatsink is required, but this does not prevent you from adding one. If your operating environment can get a bit warm and you don't want it to thermal throttle, you can add one (optionally strap a fan on it.)

I have all my Pi heatsinked since I use cases while put lots of stress on the core, and one of them have a fan strapped on it to improve cooling as it operates in a warm equipment roon with an average ambient temperature of 45ºC.

Comment: This answer touches on the key point: _measure its temperature_ if one is concerned about potential overheating.